# Calculate Datarate in influxDB 2.x Flux from Glances

Tags: grafana, influxdb

i have setup Glances on my Machine to export to Influx. I now wanted to get the Network Data Transfer rate in influx. But i noticed, that it gives wrong numbers, if I just query the rx and tx, which is exported in bits per second. My query looks like this:

```
from(bucket: "glances_fibdonas")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "network")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "rx" or r["_field"] == "tx")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["hostname"] == "FibdoNAS")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["interface_name"] == "eth0")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

I then saw a post that said I have to calculate the Bitrate from the "Time since last update":
"The received bitrate is = rx / time_since_update = 2056872 / 20.3142728805542 = 101252 B/s"

I tried to calculate with the map function in Flux, but i dont understand how to calculate with the different values i get from the database.

Can you help me with the calculation, im new to Flux :)

Answer (score 1):

the Glances API provides the computed rate per second through the rx and tx fields ([see API documentation](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/blob/develop/docs/api.rst#get-network)).

So no need to take time_since_update into account, rx/tx field are already in bits per second.